# Repeat drawing of same 5 nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-styles

I am drawing some nodes with tikz in multiple tikzpicture environments. It is the exact same nodes, so I thought it is possible to create a tikz command to draw the same 5 nodes again and again?

Would it be best practice to just use

```
\newcommand{\samefivenodes}{%
  \node (a) {a};
  \node[right=of a] (b) {b};
  \node[right=of b] (c) {c};
  \node[right=of c] (d) {d};
  \node[right=of d] (e) {e};
};
```

Comment: did you check the `chains` library of TikZ in the manual ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use these five nodes. If it is just meant as a shorthand, then `\newcommand` is fine. If it is a sub-picture, tikz offers the `\pic` command, or you can define a new shape (like rectangles, circles, diamonds) with anchors which will automatically be used when connecting the shape with other nodes.

Comment: It is a tree, so you could use Forest which can copy sub-trees multiple times. I am sorry, by the way. When I commented on your earlier question, I thought that you would obviously already know how to provide a minimal example. However, seeing this new question, I realise that I may have been mistaken and that you may so far not have been directed to the [guidance for creating a Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=3|0.6378). Just FYI, there is another one for questions about bibliographies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Forest:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  declare toks={split five}{},
  make five/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={append'=a, split five=#1, delay={split option={split five}{:}{before five,five and,just five}}},
  },
  just five/.style={
    for descendants={#1},
  },
  five and/.style={
    for tree={#1},
  },
  before five/.style={
    #1,
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  delay={
    for tree={
      if content={}{phantom}{
        name/.option=content,
        delay={content/.wrap value=\strut#1},
      },
      grow'=0,
    },
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily
    }
  }
  [[a[b[c,make five[d[e,make five=:{grow'=90}:make five]]]]][modified copy, make five={top color=black, bottom color=black, middle color=white, text=red, !1.edge=->}:{grow'=-90}:{inner color=blue!50!cyan, outer color=blue!30!cyan, text=white, thick, draw=blue!75!cyan, edge={blue!75!cyan, thick}, font=\sffamily\bfseries, circle} ]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

will create many exactly similar copies, some rotated, and one highly modified version:

[image: Forest repetition]

Comment: If I have each node is a square with side equal to 1 or a circle radius 1. How can I make  sequence of n - squares or n - cirlces? Please help me.

Comment: @toandhsp That's a different question. Please ask a new question and include the code you are using to make the one node.